# Docker Run Script to catch interruption signal

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've a docker-compose.yml which starts several containers.
One of which uses a Dockerimage file to install everything needed in that container.

I'd like to add a script which runs each time waiting for the interruption signals 0, 9 and 137.

Now, I'm trying to run the script as an Entrypoint in the Dockerimage file, but doesn't seems to work.

This is the content of the Dockerimage file :

```
RUN apt-get update && [...]
WORKDIR "/application"
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/application/scripts/cl.sh"]
```

Am I doing something wrong? Do I need to rebuild the containers with the following command?

```
docker-compose build
```

---

This is the content of the bash script cl.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "HELLO HELLO HELLO HELLO"

trap 'echo "Exiting with a 137 signal."' 137 0 9
```

The only purpose of the script at the moment is testing everything work.

Comment: Please include a [mcve], including a shell script and command/method you use to send signals. More than likely the issue is the extra /bin/bash process you're including as pid 1, but I'd like to test this before posting an answer.

Comment: @BMitch I added the script content as it is. As you can see it's just for testing it's working properly the connection with the Docker system.

Comment: Is your container still running to trap the signal? After you define the trap, your script immediately ends, which would end the container.

Comment: My container still running with no problem.. I was expecting to find some message when I stop the container with the 'docker-compose stop' command.. But nothing shows in the logs

Comment: I didn't test your whole example, but regarding the `ENTRYPOINT` command of your Dockerfile, the bash option `-c` is off-topic and should be removed, because this option is dedicated for passing *inline code* to bash, not for running an external script.

Comment: Cool! Now is working but as you said, the container stops when the script run.
Any idea how can I catch the interruption signal? The idea is to run a backup before the container stops.

Answer (score 8):

Yes it is possible to achieve what you want, but before presenting the corresponding code I have to comment on your question's code which contained some issues:

- The line `trap 'echo "Exiting with a 137 signal."' 137 0 9` is incorrect because 137 is not a valid signal number (see for example the [Wikipedia article on signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#POSIX_signals)).

  Maybe you just encountered 137 as it is the *exit code* corresponding to the *signal* 9 (given that 137 = 128 + 9, see [this appendix in the bash doc.](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html))
- 0 (EXIT) and 9 (KILL) are valid signal numbers, but in practice it is better to only trap 2 (INT) and 15 (TERM), as suggested in [this SE/Unix answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149093).

  Indeed while the INT and TERM signals can be used for "graceful termination", the KILL signal means the process must be killed immediately and as mentioned in `man trap`:

  > Setting a trap for SIGKILL or SIGSTOP produces *undefined results*.
  >   […] Trapping  SIGKILL  or SIGSTOP is syntactically accepted by some historical implementations, but it has no effect. Portable POSIX applications cannot attempt to trap these signals.
- Setting the trap at the end of the entrypoint script is a bad strategy, as it is useless in this place. Instead, I suggest that you define a cleanup function (the last instruction of which being `exit`), then set a trap on this function at the beginning of the script, and run your (non-terminating) application afterwards.

Hence the following proof-of-concept:

> Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:latest
WORKDIR /app

COPY entrypoint.bash ./
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "./entrypoint.bash"]
```

> entrypoint.bash

```
#!/bin/bash

cleanup() {
    echo "Cleaning up..."
    exit
}

trap cleanup INT TERM

while :; do
    echo "Hello! ${SECONDS} secs elapsed..."
    sleep 1s
done
```

To test it, you just need to run:

```
$ docker build -t test-trap .
$ docker run -d --name=TEST-TRAP test-trap
  # wait a few seconds
$ docker stop TEST-TRAP
$ docker logs -f TEST-TRAP
Hello! 0 secs elapsed...
Hello! 1 secs elapsed...
Hello! 2 secs elapsed...
Hello! 3 secs elapsed...
Cleaning up...
```

Comment: @LuigiT. did the proposed answer work for you?