# Speed up docker-compose shutdown

Tags: docker-compose

When I set up my application to run via `docker-compose up`, it takes several seconds to stop on ctrl+c. However, if I run `docker kill ...`, the container stops very quickly. Is there anything I can do to speed up container shutdown when killed via ctrl+c within `docker-compose up`?

In particular, what does it actually mean when docker-compose says it is "gracefully stopping "? Is docker-compose trying some shutdown protocol and then killing my container only after a timeout?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> what does it actually mean when docker-compose says it is "gracefully stopping "?

Basically when you do Ctrl+C you are sending a SIGINT (2) signal to the application that runs in the foreground. Most of the time, the semantics of this signal is similar to the SIGTERM (15) signal that is raised when doing `docker-compose stop` or more basically `docker stop` if you are focusing on a single-container application.

> Is docker-compose trying some shutdown protocol and then killing my container only after a timeout?

Yes, the idea is that the running application can catch the SIGINT and SIGTERM signal and perform some cleanup operation before exiting.

On the contrary, the SIGKILL (9) signal (raised by `docker kill` for example) causes the process to terminate immediately.

You might be interested in this related [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50278689/9164010) where I give a toy example of entrypoint bash script that "catches" SIGINT and SIGTERM signals (but not SIGKILL, of course).

> Is there anything I can do to speed up container shutdown when killed via ctrl+c within docker-compose up?

I'd say the time spent by your containers to exit when you do `docker stop` or so strongly depends on the implementation of the corresponding images.

At first sight, you might modify (e.g., shorten) the time offered to the containers to gracefully stop:

- `docker stop -t TIMEOUT` [(doc)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/#options)
- `docker-compose stop -t TIMEOUT` [(doc)](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/stop/)

but this would certainly not be a proper solution.

Actually, there are two **typical pitfalls** when one comes to rely on an **entrypoint bash script**:

1. Use a bash script as a wrapper to finally call another program, but forget to use the `exec` builtin.
   → The recommended practice consists in prepending the last command of a bash entrypoint with `exec`
   (for example, see [this line from `entrypointd.sh` in `sudo-bmitch/docker-base`](https://github.com/sudo-bmitch/docker-base/blob/f1b7e1a775d41d93b354037f193c2dcc8946ee34/bin/entrypointd.sh#L66)).
2. When the bash script itself should not terminate immediately, one could forget to take care of trapping the signals (including SIGINT and SIGTERM) and behave accordingly, which can also be the cause of the issue you observe. This is related to the so-called [PID 1 zombie reaping problem](https://blog.phusion.nl/2015/01/20/docker-and-the-pid-1-zombie-reaping-problem/).
   → To workaround this, you may want to run your image with the `docker run` flag [`--init`](https://github.com/krallin/tini#using-tini), or add the `docker-compose.yml` parameter [`init`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#init) [(related SO Q.)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50356032/9164010)

Answer (score 17):

If you find yourself restarting containers frequently and some don't gracefully exit or have long exit times (ie. you want *more* than 10s before it's killed), you can now do this per-service/container with [`stop_grace_period`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#stop_grace_period)

> `stop_grace_period` specifies how long the Compose implementation MUST wait when attempting to stop a container if it doesn’t handle `SIGTERM` (or whichever stop signal has been specified with [`stop_signal`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#stopsignal)), before sending SIGKILL. Specified as a [duration](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#specifying-durations).

For example

```yaml
services:
  service_A:
    ...
    stop_grace_period: 1s  # SIGKILL after 1s
  service_B:
    ...
    stop_grace_period: 5m30s  # wait a long time before SIGKILL
```

---

This should be supported in all formats (2.0+) and the release notes suggest it's been available (in compose) from [1.10.0](https://docs.docker.com/compose/release-notes/#1100) (2017-01-18 which also introduced the 3.0 `docker-compose.yml` spec) and had an important fix in [1.18.0](https://docs.docker.com/compose/release-notes/#1180) (2017-12-18 *"Setting `stop_grace_period` in service definitions now also sets the container's `stop_timeout`"*)

Comment: You've saved me weeks and month of my life. I love you <3
I always have this problem with `nodejs` containers, but until now I haven't found out why. It seems like either `trap 'exit 1' TERM INT` or `exec` is missing in the `ENTRYPOINT`+`CMD` chain, but I cant exactly say (otherwise I'd have fixed it by now)
This "quickfix" does the trick for me.

Comment: @Iyashi glad to help! https://xkcd.com/1495/ naïvely, it might be waiting on active connections and either a second `SIGTERM` or `SIGKILL` will end it