# Executing `sh -c` in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a `test.sh` file which takes as a parameter a bash command, it does some logic, i.e. setting and checking some env vars, and then executes that input command.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

#Some other logic here

echo "Run command: $@"
eval "$@"
```

When I run it, here's the output

```sh
% ./test.sh echo "ok"        
Run command: echo ok
ok
```

**But the issue is**, when I pass something like `sh -c 'echo "ok"'`, I don't get the output.

```sh
% ./test.sh sh -c 'echo "ok"'
Run command: sh -c echo "ok"

%
```

So I tried changing `eval` with `exec`, tried to execute `$@` directly (without `eval` or `exec`), even tried to execute it and save the output to a variable, still no use.

Is there any way to run the passed command in this format and get the ourput?

---

Use case:
The script is used as an entrypoint for the docker container, it receives the parameters from docker CMD and executes those to run the container.

As a quickfix I can remove the `sh -c` and pass the command without it, but I want to make the script reusable and not to change the commands.

Comment: Using just `"$@"` works for me.

Comment: @BenjaminW. ohh `"$@"` worked for me as well, won't work without the quotes (`$@`)

Comment: Yes, without the quotes, the parameter `echo "ok"` will be split into two parameters.

Comment: yeah I see, thanks. Want to post it as an answer?

Comment: And for the use case you mention, prepending `"$@"` with `exec` in the last line of the entrypoint script is recommended → `exec "$@"`

Comment: ^ That would be the better answer then :)

Comment: haha fair :) @ErikMD want to post the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR:

This is a typical use case (perform some business logic in a Docker entrypoint script before running a compound command, given at command line) and the recommended last line of the script is:

```
exec "$@"
```

### Details

To further explain this line, some remarks and hyperlinks:

1. As per the [Bash user manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins), `exec` is a POSIX shell builtin that *replaces the shell [with the command supplied] **without creating a new process***.
2. As a result, using `exec` like this in a Docker entrypoint context is important because it ensures that the `CMD` program that is executed will still **have PID 1 and can directly handle signals**, including that of `docker stop` (see also that other SO answer: [Speed up docker-compose shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50536078/9164010)).
3. The double quotes (`"$@"`) are also important to **avoid word splitting** (namely, ensure that each positional argument is passed as is, even if it contains spaces). See e.g.:

   ```
    #!/usr/bin/env bash

    printargs () { for arg; do echo "$arg"; done; }

    test0 () {
        echo "test0:"
        printargs $@
    }

    test1 () {
        echo "test1:"
        printargs "$@"
    }

    test0 /bin/sh -c 'echo "ok"'
    echo
    test1 /bin/sh -c 'echo "ok"'
   ```

   > ```
   > test0:
   > /bin/sh
   > -c
   > echo
   > "ok"
   >
   > test1:
   > /bin/sh
   > -c
   > echo "ok"
   > ```
4. Finally `eval` is a powerful bash builtin that is (1) unneeded for your use case, (2) and actually not advised to use in general, in particular for **security reasons**. E.g., if the string argument of `eval` relies on some user-provided input… For details on this issue, see e.g. https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048 (which recaps the few situations where one would like to use this builtin, typically, the command `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`).