# Catching SIGTERM from alpine image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, gitlab-ci-runner, alpine-linux, sigkill

I was trying to catch SIGTERM signal from a docker instance (basically when docker stop is called) but couldn't find a way since I have different results for each try I performed.

Following is the setup I have

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine

COPY ./start.sh /start.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/start.sh"]
```

**start.sh**

```sh
#!/bin/bash

deregister_runner() {
    echo "even if nothing happened, something happened"
    exit
}
trap deregister_runner SIGTERM

while true; do
    sleep 10
done
```

Now I build the docker image

```
$ docker build -t dockertrapcatch .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  51.71kB
Step 1/3 : FROM gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine
 ---> 9f8c39873bee
Step 2/3 : COPY ./start.sh /start.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ebb3cac0c509
Step 3/3 : ENTRYPOINT ["/start.sh"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7ab67fe5a714
Successfully built 7ab67fe5a714
Successfully tagged dockertrapcatch:latest
```

Run the docker

```sh
$ docker run -it dockertrapcatch
```

Now when I run `docker stop <<container_id_here>>` or `docker kill --signal=SIGTERM <<container_id_here>>`, my **deregister_runner** function is not called.

After that I changed the **start.sh** script as following (SIGKILL ==> EXIT)

```sh
#!/bin/bash

deregister_runner() {
    echo "even if nothing happened, something happened"
    exit
}
trap deregister_runner EXIT

while true; do
    sleep 10
done
```

After this change and creating the docker image and running it `docker stop <<container_id_here>>` still does not work but `docker kill --signal=SIGTERM <<container_id_here>>` works!

```sh
$ docker run -it dockertrapcatch
even if nothing happened, something happened
```

```sh
$ docker kill --signal=SIGTERM 6b667af4ac6c
6b667af4ac6c
```

I read that actually `docker stop` sends a **SIGTERM** but I think this time it is not working? Any idea?

Comment: I believe [this other StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50536078/9164010) might be useful for your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker Run Script to catch interruption signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50257930/docker-run-script-to-catch-interruption-signal)

Comment: Actually the base image you use seems to behave differently w.r.t. that of the thread I mentioned… I'll try to recap this in a more complete answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue you raise, while it does not show up when I replace the base image with `debian:10`, for example.

It happens the issue is not due to `alpine` but to the `gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine` image itself, namely [this `Dockerfile`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/blob/b78aed5a4867d3342cf9a7ef2d24ee214402b3be/dockerfiles/alpine/Dockerfile#L42) contains the following line:

> `STOPSIGNAL SIGQUIT`

To be more precise, the line above means `docker stop` will send a `SIGQUIT` signal to the running containers (and wait for a "graceful termination time" before killing the containers, as if a `docker kill` were issued in the end).

If this Dockerfile directive is not used, [the default signal sent by `docker stop` is SIGTERM](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/).

Beware that `SIGKILL` would be a very poor choice for `STOPSIGNAL`, given that the KILL signal cannot be trapped.

So, your first example should work if you use the following line:

```
trap deregister_runner SIGINT SIGQUIT SIGTERM
```

This way, your cleanup function `deregister_runner` will be triggered anytime you issue a `docker stop`, or use the `Ctrl-C` keybinding (thanks to `SIGINT`).

Finally, two additional notes related to this question of `Docker`, `bash` and signals:

- The "graceful termination time" (between stop and kill) can be customized, and there are some pitfalls when using a Bash entrypoint (regarding the "signal propagation"). I explained both issues in more detail in this SO answer: [Speed up docker-compose shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50536078/9164010).
- Beware that in many `alpine` images, `bash` is not pre-installed, e.g.:

  ```
  $ sudo docker run --rm -it alpine /bin/bash
    /usr/bin/docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
    container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused
    "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory": unknown.
  ```

  (fortunately, this was not the case of `gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine`, which indeed contains the `bash` package :)